# Multiple level inheritance in WCF in C#

Tags: c#, wcf, inheritance, serialization

I have three classes:

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(B))]
[KnownType(typeof(C))]
public class A
{
   [DataMember]
   public string Value { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class B : A
{
   [DataMember]
   public string OtherValue { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class C : B
{
   [DataMember]
   public string AnotherValue { get; set; }
}
```

When I'm trying to create class C and send it using WCF, it complains:

Element 'http://tempuri.org/:B' contains data from a type that maps to the name 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/C'. The deserializer has no knowledge of any type that maps to this name. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add the type corresponding to 'C' to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding it to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.'.

Did I put the KnownType attribute in the wrong place? or I cant create such classes?

When I create class B, it does work.

Thanks

Comment: Did you tried setting the attribute `[KnownType(typeof(C))]` on class `B`?

Comment: Yeah I've tried that..didnt work